# RDD to DataFrame in pyspark (columns from rdd's first element)

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have created a rdd from a csv file and the first row is the header line in that csv file. Now I want to create dataframe from that rdd and retain the column from 1st element of rdd.

Problem is I am able to create the dataframe and with column from rdd.first(), but the created dataframe has its first row as the headers itself. How to remove that?

```
lines = sc.textFile('/path/data.csv')
rdd = lines.map(lambda x: x.split('#####'))  ###multiple char sep can be there #### or #@# , so can't directly read csv to a dataframe
#rdd: [[u'mailid', u'age', u'address'], [u'satya', u'23', u'Mumbai'], [u'abc', u'27', u'Goa']]  ###first element is the header
df = rdd.toDF(rdd.first())  ###retaing te column from rdd.first()
df.show()
#mailid  age  address
 mailid  age  address   ####I don't want this as dataframe data
 satya    23  Mumbai
 abc      27  Goa
```

How to avoid that first element moving to dataframe data. Can I give any option in rdd.toDF(rdd.first()) to get that done??

Note: I can't collect rdd to form list , then remove first item from that list, then parallelize that list back to form rdd again and then toDF()...

Please suggest!!!Thanks

Comment: why don't you read it in the CSV format as a DataFrame directly ?

Comment: @eliasah- Spark can't read files with more than one character delimiters(like ##### or #@#)  to form dataframe by (spark.read.csv or by databricks csv package)   and i have such kind of files to read also.

Comment: so remove the header before converting your rdd into a DF. Plus in your question the delimiter is a pipe. So wouldn't guess the "more than one character delimiter" issue

Comment: I asked a question to get any generalized solution to achieve that. As I mentioned there are files where multiple sep can be there. And the file is generating dynamically , so if I remove that I may not be able to retain the column names from my program(though i can save in notepad and place it in console). To get it generalized if you have any suggestion please suggest. I edited the sep,, so no confusion on "This can't be read directly to dataframe".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to remove the header from your `RDD`. One way to do it is the following considering your `rdd` variable :

```
>>> header = rdd.first()
>>> header
# ['mailid', 'age', 'address']
>>> data = rdd.filter(lambda row : row != header).toDF(header)
>>> data.show()
# +------+---+-------+
# |mailid|age|address|
# +------+---+-------+
# | satya| 23| Mumbai|
# |   abc| 27|    Goa|
# +------+---+-------+
```