# How to convert the first row as column from an existing dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like below. I want to convert the first row as columns for this dataframe.
How could I do this. Is there any way to convert it directly.(without using df.first)

```
usdata.show()
-----+---+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|        _1|       _2|                  _3|                  _4|           _5|
+----------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|first_name|last_name|        company_name|             address|         city|
|     James|     Butt| "Benton, John B Jr"|  6649 N Blue Gum St|  New Orleans|
| Josephine|  Darakjy|"Chanay, Jeffrey ...| 4 B Blue Ridge Blvd|     Brighton|
|       Art|   Venere|"Chemel, James L ...|8 W Cerritos Ave #54|   Bridgeport|
|     Lenna| Paprocki|Feltz Printing Se...|         639 Main St|    Anchorage|
+----------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

Regards,
Dinesh

Comment: Just use spark.read.option("header","true")...

Comment: Hi @RajatTanwar, I am not reading this from csv file or text file. I used to read RDD for doing some transformations and converting that to dataframe.

Comment: Ok got it, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255149/rdd-to-dataframe-in-pyspark-columns-from-rdds-first-element